# Building Chromium for Snapdragon - no "swe_browser_apk" target

Tags: android, chromium, webviewchromium

I've followed [build instructions](https://wiki.codeaurora.org/xwiki/bin/Chromium+for+Snapdragon/Stable+Build+Instructions) for Chromium for Snapdragon m54 stable build. I've added google play libs manually (as library_project is now missing in SDK). On

```
ninja -C out/Default swe_browser_apk
```

i'm getting error that "swe_browser_apk" target is not found.

```
gn ls out/Default
```

shows that there are lots of other targets including `chrome_public_apk`.
Why is `swe_browser_apk` missing? Any newer instructions since that times?

Update 1: i was unable to find "swe_browser_apk" in .gn files so is build doc outdated/incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much more easier to checkout `m58` (instead of `m54`) branch and modify `.gclient` file to use `git://codeaurora.org/quic/chrome4sdp/chromium/src.git@refs/remotes/origin/m58`. Just like it's written in the build instructions you will get `SWE_Browser.apk` in `out/Default/apks` (`swe_browser_apk` target exists).